# NTP permission issue

Tags: linux, cron, sudo, centos7, ntp

I gave everyone in my team a copy of a centos 7 virtual machine.  The time can get out of sync.  I found that I can manually update the time by using the command below:

```
[no_sudo@rolling ~]$ ntpdate pool.ntp.org
26 Apr 18:10:11 ntpdate[25928]: bind() fails: Permission denied
[no_sudo@rolling ~]$
```

However I can only update it as sudo.  One of the commands I made for the team runs some automated testing, and uses the date.time as a name.

How can I ether automate the updating of time on the virtual machine, or alter the permissions of that service, so anyone can run it regardless or permissions.

Thanks!

Comment: [no_sudo@rolling ~]$ ntpd
    must be run as root, not uid 1000
    [co_sudo@rolling ~]$

Comment: This question is better suited for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"How can I ether automate the updating of time on the virtual machine"*

The ntp daemon, `ntpd`, should take care of this. Sure it's running?

```
# start the ntp daemon
/etc/init.d/ntpd start
```

You could also add a daily or hourly entry in root's crontab that updates the time:

```
# To edit root's crontab
sudo crontab -e
# Add this line to run the command every day at noon (change as needed):
* 12 * * * /usr/sbin/ntpdate
```

*"alter the permissions of that service, so anyone can run it"*

This undermines the security model. However, if the users are allowed to use `sudo` already, you could allow password-less execution of that single executable so it won't block your script:

```
# To edit the sudoers file:
sudo visudo
# Then add something like this depending on the location of ntpdate:
username ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/ntpdate
```

Comment: /etc/init.d/ntpd start
-bash: /etc/init.d/ntpd: No such file or directory
:(

Comment: @jeff_h Maybe... I'm not too familiar with your particular distro. `ntpd` is found in most distros but paths and command syntax change. Does `systemctl start ntpd` and `systemctl enable ntpd` work? `systemctl status ntpd` to see if it's running

Answer (score 0):

You should configure and use `ntpd` instead of `ntpdate`.

Comment: [no_sudo@rolling ~]$ ntpdmust be run as root, not uid 1000

Comment: From your comment above, it seems you do not have ntpd on your host. You have to install and configure it. You need root permissions for running both ntpdate and ntpd. ntpd is better as it will keep your computers synchronized all the time. ntpdate cannot do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
\#!/bin/sh

\#script to set the time using google - my ISP is blocking access to ntp server! major bummer!! :(

HOST="www.google.co.ke"

ping -q -c 2 $HOST > /dev/null 2>&1 

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then

echo "----\`date\`---------------------FAILURE----------------------------------" 

  echo "Failure: \`date\` -- $HOST is is DOWN! >>> better luck next time!"

else

echo "****\`date\`*********************BEGIN: SUCCESS*********************************"

mydateold="\`date\`"

  echo "Success: \`date\` -- $HOST is UP >>> set the time!"

  date -s "$(date -d "\`curl http://www.google.co.ke -v 2>&1 |   grep "Date: " | awk '{ print $3 " " $5 " " $4 " " $7 " " $6 " GMT"}'\`")"

mynewdate="\`date\`"

echo "Success: \`date\` >>> Date updated: OLD DATETIME: $mydateold and NEW DATETIME: 

$mynewdate"

echo "****\`date\`*********************END: SUCCESS***********************************"

fi

\#EOF

\#Powered By Slackware Linux :)
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation or context to your answers.